# Modify Code - Find & Replace Text in a cell Google Apps Script / Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below does as intended if AU5000 is the only thing in the cell - however I need a slight modification.My cell contains job numbers like this AU500014234. I would like the script to remove the AU5000 and leave the remaining 5 numbers i.e 14234

```
function fandr() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
var r=s.getDataRange();
var vlst=r.getValues();
var i,j,a,find,repl;
find="AU5000";
repl="";
for (i in vlst) {
for (j in vlst[i]) {
a=vlst[i][j];
if (a==find) vlst[i][j]=repl;
}
}
r.setValues(vlst);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This can be done in Apps Script much easier with [replaceAllWith()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceallwithreplacetext)

Sample:

```
function replaceAllSubstrings(){
  var find="AU5000";
  var repl="";
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().createTextFinder(find).replaceAllWith(repl);  
}
```